# NoMethodError for Devise current_user when calling associated has_many model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm following along with One Month Rails and I got stuck at the Pins Users and Associations video. I just can't figure out what's wrong with my code, any help would be appreciated.

When I try to access a pin that I'm not the user of, instead of an alert and redirect coming up I get:

```
NoMethodError in PinsController#edit

undefined method `pins' for nil:NilClass
```

Error message says something is wrong in this line:

```
        def correct_user
          @pin = current_user.pins.find_by(id: params[:id])
          redirect_to pins_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this pin" if @pin.nil?
        end
```

I tried restarting the whole thing but I hit the same error.

Here is my pins_controller code:

```
class PinsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :set_pin, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]

  def index
    @pins = Pin.all
  end

   def show
  end

  def new
    @pin = current_user.pins.build
  end

  def edit
  end

  def create
    @pin = current_user.pins.build(pin_params)
    if @pin.save
      redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully created.'
    else
      render action: 'new'
    end
  end

  def update
    if @pin.update(pin_params)
      redirect_to @pin, notice: 'Pin was successfully updated.'
    else
      render action: 'edit'
    end
  end

  def destroy
    @pin.destroy
    redirect_to pins_url
  end

  private
    # Use callbacks to share common setup or constraints between actions.
    def set_pin
      @pin = Pin.find(params[:id])
    end

    def correct_user
      @pin = current_user.pins.find_by(id: params[:id])
      redirect_to pins_path, notice: "Not authorized to edit this pin" if @pin.nil?
    end

    # Never trust parameters from the scary internet, only allow the white list through.
    def pin_params
      params.require(:pin).permit(:description)
    end
end
```

Here is my user.rb model code:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
      # Include default devise modules. Others available are:
      # :token_authenticatable, :confirmable,
      # :lockable, :timeoutable and :omniauthable
          devise :database_authenticatable, :registerable,
             :recoverable, :rememberable, :trackable, :validatable

      has_many :pins
    end
```

Here is my pin.rb model code:

```
    class Pin < ActiveRecord::Base
        belongs_to :user
    end
```

And here is the github repo:
https://github.com/ModernMeat/pinteresting

Comment: How are you defining `current_user`, where are you instantiating it? The error code is suggesting that `current_user` doesn't exist (is nil).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would suggest you to change order of `before_filter`'s like this

```
class PinsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!, except: [:index, :show]
  before_action :set_pin, only: [:show, :edit, :update, :destroy]
  before_action :correct_user, only: [:edit, :update, :destroy]
```

because you should first authenticate user with devise and only after that check whether it is correct user.

Comment: This worked, thanks a lot! Seems like a really simple solution, I guess I should have tried to think about the order in which things have to happen instead of following the tutorial.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the error message a bit more closely : `"for nil:NilClass"`. This tells you that `current_user` is `nil` -- which it is indeed, when the user is not logged in.

If you want to make sure the user is logged in to access to the `Pins` controller, you can use a `before_action` in your controller :

```
class PinsController < ApplicationController
  before_action :authenticate_user!
```

(`authenticate_user!` being a method declared by devise).